# equivalent of ruby Hash#reject in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

What's the closest equivalent to ruby's Hash#reject/delete_if method?

```
{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}.reject { |k,v| v > 2 }
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

this quick version uses `key, value of <Object>` but it's not elegant, and lacks the ability to pass an arbitrary condition (as a block or otherwise)

```
params = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
filter = (hash)->
    result = {}
    (result[key] = value unless value > 2) for key, value of params
    result

console.log(filter(params))
```

underscore has a similar `_.omit` method, but only works on keys.

Comment: You could pass a function to `filter` (`filter(obj, (k,v) -> ...)`) and then `result[k] = v for k,v of params when fn(v)` inside `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately CoffeeScript comprehensions always generate arrays. You could use Underscore's [`object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object) method to transform a `[key, value]` array into an object:

```
obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}
_.object([k, v] for k, v of obj when v <= 2) # -> {a:1, b:2}
```

I'd recommend you code your own method for this specific purpose though:

```
reject = (obj, predicate) ->
  res = {}
  res[k] = v for k, v of obj when not predicate k, v
  res

reject {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, (k, v) -> v > 2 # -> {a:1, b:2}
```